# Make gauge charts through matplotlib side by side

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to follow this [tutorial](http://nicolasfauchereau.github.io/climatecode/posts/drawing-a-gauge-with-matplotlib/) to make a gauge matplotlib plot and I am able to make three of them. I am wondering how to make them side by side. [I am just following the original code from the url]

```
gauge(labels=['LOW','MEDIUM','HIGH','EXTREME'], \
      colors=['#007A00','#0063BF','#FFCC00','#ED1C24'], arrow=3, title='something') 

gauge(labels=['LOW','MEDIUM','HIGH','EXTREME'], \
      colors=['#007A00','#0063BF','#FFCC00','#ED1C24'], arrow=3, title='anything') 

gauge(labels=['LOW','MEDIUM','HIGH','EXTREME'], \
      colors=['#007A00','#0063BF','#FFCC00','#ED1C24'], arrow=3, title='nothing')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactor the `gauge` function so it accepts an `ax` argument:

```
def gauge(labels, colors, arrow, title, ax):
    # other code
    # ...

    # remove this
    # fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    # other code

    ax.set_frame_on(False)
    ax.axes.set_xticks([])
    ax.axes.set_yticks([])
    ax.axis('equal')
    # remove this as well
    # plt.tight_layout()
```

Then you can call:

```
# create the axes
# play with the numbers
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,3)

gauge(labels=['LOW','MEDIUM','HIGH','EXTREME'], \
      colors=['#007A00','#0063BF','#FFCC00','#ED1C24'], arrow=3, title='something',
      ax=axes[0])

 gauge(labels=['LOW','MEDIUM','HIGH','EXTREME'], \
      colors=['#007A00','#0063BF','#FFCC00','#ED1C24'], arrow=3, title='anything',
      ax=axes[1]) 

gauge(labels=['LOW','MEDIUM','HIGH','EXTREME'], \
      colors=['#007A00','#0063BF','#FFCC00','#ED1C24'], arrow=3, title='nothing',
      ax=axes[2])
```

Comment: Thanks so much. If I remove `fname` from the function, I am wondering how to save the three side-by-side plot in this case.

Comment: `fig.savefig('filename.png')` after the code?

Comment: I have got the error `AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'savefig'`. Any idea I can overcome this?

Comment: What version is your matplotlib, I do see it [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html?highlight=figure#matplotlib.figure.Figure).

Comment: I am using 3.3.0 and given I am in the locked environment, I don't think I can change the version. I tried back the `fname` argument but it doesn't seem to save three plots png.

Comment: Nope, it's [there](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html?highlight=figure#matplotlib.figure.Figure) on 3.3.0. Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: I'd try to figure this out or try in a different question then. Many thanks!